# How to run tests sequentially in Xcode 6 beta3

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, integration-testing

From what I can see, it looks like Xcode runs tests from a given TestCase sequentially, but from different TestCases in parallel.

Is it possible to configure a project/target so that all the tests run sequentially ?
For instance, this would be useful to run various integration tests that have side effects  affecting the other tests. (e.g. access to same database tables)

EDIT: to clear out some confusion: I am not talking about forcing a specific sequence of tests, just about making sure that the tests do not interfere with each other.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe, but it's generally a bad idea to rely on test A running before test B will succeed.

Comment: Let me correct: I am not talking about reusing the output of A before executing B. I am talking about making sure that A and B do not interfere with each other (because they use a common database table, for instance)

Comment: I understand.  Each test should be self-contained and needs to set-up the test environment the way they like before running.  This makes them more flexible and you can repeatedly run a single test if you are fixing something in that area.

Comment: I fully agree. But when relying for instance on Core Data, it isn't that easy to achieve because I cannot just setup different unrelated contexts.

Comment: When running unit tests that rely on Core Data, I find it easiest to set up and populate an in memory store in the setUp method.  Anything else risks the tests not being independent.

Comment: What makes you think that different test cases are running in parallel? I've never observed that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If you need your objects to have a consistent starting state for tests, I would recommend adding calls to the setUp method of your test classes. setUp called before each of the tests in a test class.

If you need your suite to run in a certain order, it sounds like you don't have unit tests and are running integration tests. You can try to use setUp to initialize your lower-level objects. If you are only interested in the behavior of a higher-level class, try mocks. The OCMock framework is available for Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this solves your problem, but could you manage to put the tests into a serial queue? It allows you to run them concurrently yet to wait for the barriers to be cleared.

```
func dispatch_barrier_async(_ queue: dispatch_queue_t,
                      _ block: dispatch_block_t)
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_barrier_async

Alternatively, you can setup multiple contexts and merge them afterwards.